# How can I sanitize user input with PHP?

Tags: php, security, xss, sql-injection, user-input

Is there a catchall function somewhere that works well for sanitizing user input for SQL injection and XSS attacks, while still allowing certain types of HTML tags?

Answer (score 1307, accepted):

It's a common misconception that user input can be filtered. PHP even had a (now defunct) "feature", called [magic-quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_quotes), that builds on this idea. It's nonsense. Forget about filtering (or cleaning, or whatever people call it).

What you should do, to avoid problems, is quite simple: whenever you embed a piece of data within a foreign code, you must format it according to the rules of that code. But you must understand that such rules could be too complicated to try to follow them all manually. For example, in SQL, rules for strings, numbers and identifiers are all different. For your convenience, in most cases there is a dedicated tool for such embedding. For example, when some data has to be used in the SQL query, instead of adding a variable directly to SQL string, it has to be done though a parameter in the query, using prepared statement. And it will take care of all the proper formatting.

Another example is HTML: If you embed strings within HTML markup, you must escape it with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php). This means that every single `echo` or `print` statement should use `htmlspecialchars`.

A third example could be shell commands: If you are going to embed strings (such as arguments) to external commands, and call them with [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/function.exec.php), then you must use [`escapeshellcmd`](http://php.net/manual/function.escapeshellcmd.php) and [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/function.escapeshellarg.php).

Also, a very compelling example is JSON. The rules are so numerous and complicated that you would never be able to follow them all manually. That's why you should never ever create a JSON string manually, but always use a dedicated function, [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) that will correctly format every bit of data.

And so on and so forth ...

The *only* case where you need to actively filter data, is if you're accepting preformatted input. For example, if you let your users post HTML markup, that you plan to display on the site. However, you should be wise to avoid this at all cost, since no matter how well you filter it, it will always be a potential security hole.

Comment: "This means that every single echo or print statement should use htmlspecialchars" - of course, you mean "every ... statement outputting user input"; htmlspecialchars()-ifying "echo 'Hello, world!';" would be crazy ;)

Comment: There's one case where I think filtering is the right solution: UTF-8. You don't want invalid UTF-8 sequences all over your application (you might get different error recovery depending on code path), and UTF-8 can be filtered (or rejected) easily.

Comment: @porneL: Yes, and it can also be worthwhile to filter out control characters other than newline at this point. However given that most PHP apps can't even get the HTML-escaping right yet I'm not going to push the overlong UTF-8 sequence issue (they're only really an issue in IE6 pre-Service-Pack-2 and old Operas).

Comment: Although your answer is helpful, HTML can and is successfully filtered for XSS in numerous applications. E.g. Comment systems in blog software such as WordPress.

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but as of PHP 5.2.0 PHP has introduced Filters (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) and the function filter_var(), which when passed a value and an appropriate filter will either sanitize or validate the supplied user input.

Comment: @david 5.2.0 was out when I made this answer.

Comment: Hi Troels -- Thanks for the answer. Most of the frameworks & languages I use every day, including PHP, Javascript and the Apache web server, have failed spectacularly at 'sanitizing' input in the past (magic quotes OMG!), and if they can't get it right, what chance do I have?
Currently, I use prepared statements for all SQL I ever write, and for html I use a variant of htmlspecialchars, and frankly I'm still not 100% sure I'm not missing something. Security is HARD.

Comment: @Jens Roland -- You're quite right; Security is hard. Trying to delegate it to a framework is probably not a good strategy. Much better to actually understand what we're dealing with. It sounds like you have the most common bases covered though.

Comment: But will mysql_real_escape_string properly handle the following:

$sub = mysql_real_escape_string("%something"); // still %something 
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE subject LIKE '{$sub}%'");

...?

Comment: @jbyrd - no, LIKE uses a specialised regexp language. You will have to escape your input string twice - once for the regexp and once for the mysql string encoding. It's code within code within code.

Comment: before you use `mysql_real_escape_string` , you should be connected to a database.

Comment: At this moment `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated. It's considered good practice nowadays to use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent SQL injection. So switch to either MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: I haven't touched PHP for a long while; coming back to it and seeing this answer about the deprecation of magic quotes makes me happy.

Comment: While useful, this doesn't answer the actual question.  They wanted to allow some HTML tags in the input.  The only advice here on how to do that is to consider not allowing them by using htmlspecialchars.  Supporting them may be some sort of customer requirement.  I have seen a number of websites that support some HTML markup (e.g. slashdot.org) on input, so I can only assume it's possible.

Comment: @troelskn `The only case where you need to actively filter data, is if you're accepting preformatted input. Eg. if you let your users post HTML markup, that you plan to display on the site.` but if you don't sanitize the input (a $_POST for example), then a user can always input html right? So... Here you are saying that you should sanitize every user input, because a user can enter html code anywhere if you don't sanitize it. Or have i gotten this wrong somehow?

Comment: @tastro No, you don't sanitize when data is input - you sanitize when it's used. E.g. as late as possible. That will give you the best level of security.

Comment: @troelskn could you tell me `why` it will give me the best level of security if i do it as late as possible? Thanks!

Comment: Because you limit the attack surface. If you sanitize early (when input), you have to be certain that there are no other holes in the application where bad data could enter through. Whereas if you do it late, then your output function doesn't have to "trust" that it is given safe data - it simply assumes that everything is unsafe.

Comment: @troelskn can you include "escape" code for each of the examples?

Comment: Question: Would you need to sanitize/validate user input if you were using that input to make a curl post request?

Comment: @sudosoul probably not. Depending on how you pass data to curl, you will need to serialize/encode it properly though.

Comment: Should I infer from this answer that (arbitrary) input categorically cannot be filtered? I don't follow.

Comment: @troelskn I was mostly thinking about the SQL part. As in: use of prepared statements instead of escaping.

Comment: I did the following: `<input type="hidden" name="my-val" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['my-val']); ?>"/>` and the Url is `http://example.com?my-val=<test>this` and value is still `<test>this` in the hidden statement

Comment: so `htmlspecialchars()` and prepared statements are enough to sanitize user input from `input` elements that is inserted into the db?!

Comment: @Si8 apparently `<?=` has been removed from PHP 7+

Comment: @troelskn "If you sanitize early you have to be certain that there are no other holes in the application where bad data could enter through" You have the same problem when doing it late: You have to be certain that there are no other holes in the application where you are using the data. Intuitively, it seems easier to me to miss a data-usage than a data-input.

Comment: @BobbyJack Hope in the course of those 12 years you've learned enough to disavow your comment. What would be *indeed* crazy is to distinctly judge every piece of data and decide whether it's pure enough to escape the common treatment, under a constant danger of [making a human error in such a judgement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22534183/285587).

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for the feedback, although it comes across as a *little* confrontational, especially for this site! I wouldn't disavow that comment, though. I don't think "echo 'hello world';" should be written "echo htmlspecialchars('hello world');". Obviously, I take your point, but I think it's taking defensive programming to an extreme. I'd be very interested to see an example of that approach in a significant codebase, though, if you have one.

Comment: @BobbyJack I understand you didn't mean any harm and all you wanted is to make a quip. But people often underestimate the consequences. You mentioned "user input" in your comment while this term is vague and uncertain, often being completely misunderstood, as it's proven by the link I provided. That's why modern template engines are "taking defensive programming to an extreme" with their auto-escaping feature, completely disregarding the input source. Your distorted example is correct but your broader statement is not. That's the problem with information on Stack Overflow at whole.

Comment: Take, for example, the notorious SQL "escaping" case. In some narrow context it could help against SQL injection, BUT it in the mass conscience it was extended to being an all-embracing protection measure. With disastrous consequences. Even making technically correct statements that escaping only help for "strings" doesn't help as people just overlook this, having a vague idea on what an SQL string is. It requires helluvalot of explanation to explain how SQL injection protection that involves escaping works. That's why there are parameterized queries that do 100% protection when applicable

Comment: @Loduwijk: If it's easier for you to not miss data-input, then consider everything your scripts get as input from the database as what it is: (user) input.

Answer (score 249):

Do not try to prevent SQL injection by sanitizing input data.

Instead, **do not allow data to be used in creating your SQL code**.  Use Prepared Statements (i.e. using parameters in a template query) that uses bound variables.  It is the only way to be guaranteed against SQL injection.

Please see my website http://bobby-tables.com/ for more about preventing SQL injection.

Comment: Or visit the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and learn PDO and prepared statements.  Tiny learning curve, but if you know SQL pretty well, you'll have no trouble adapting.

Comment: For the specific case of SQL Injection, *this* is the correct answer!

Comment: Note that prepared statements don't add any security, parameterised queries do. They just happen to be very easy to use together in PHP.

Comment: Its not the only guaranteed way. Hex the input and unhex in query will prevent also. Also hex attacks are not possible if you use hexing right.

Comment: What if you're inputting something specialized, like email addresses or usernames?

Comment: If you need dynamic *order by* PDO doesn't support it so you still need to take height for that with input validation

Comment: What would you do with email or password while user registering?

Comment: Use prepared statements and bind variables.

Answer (score 84):

No.  You can't generically filter data without any context of what it's for.  Sometimes you'd want to take a SQL query as input and sometimes you'd want to take HTML as input.

You need to filter input on a whitelist -- ensure that the data matches some specification of what you expect.  Then you need to escape it before you use it, depending on the context in which you are using it.

The process of escaping data for SQL - to prevent SQL injection - is very different from the process of escaping data for (X)HTML, to prevent XSS.

Answer (score 63):

PHP has the new nice [`filter_input`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) functions now, that for instance liberate you from finding 'the ultimate e-mail regex' now that there is a built-in `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` type

---

My own filter class (uses JavaScript to highlight faulty fields) can be initiated by either an ajax request or normal form post. (see the example below)
<?
/**
*  Pork Formvalidator. validates fields by regexes and can sanitize them. Uses PHP filter_var built-in functions and extra regexes
*  @package pork
*/

```
/**
 *  Pork.FormValidator
 *  Validates arrays or properties by setting up simple arrays. 
 *  Note that some of the regexes are for dutch input!
 *  Example:
 * 
 *  $validations = array('name' => 'anything','email' => 'email','alias' => 'anything','pwd'=>'anything','gsm' => 'phone','birthdate' => 'date');
 *  $required = array('name', 'email', 'alias', 'pwd');
 *  $sanitize = array('alias');
 *
 *  $validator = new FormValidator($validations, $required, $sanitize);
 *                  
 *  if($validator->validate($_POST))
 *  {
 *      $_POST = $validator->sanitize($_POST);
 *      // now do your saving, $_POST has been sanitized.
 *      die($validator->getScript()."<script type='text/javascript'>alert('saved changes');</script>");
 *  }
 *  else
 *  {
 *      die($validator->getScript());
 *  }   
 *  
 * To validate just one element:
 * $validated = new FormValidator()->validate('blah@bla.', 'email');
 * 
 * To sanitize just one element:
 * $sanitized = new FormValidator()->sanitize('<b>blah</b>', 'string');
 * 
 * @package pork
 * @author SchizoDuckie
 * @copyright SchizoDuckie 2008
 * @version 1.0
 * @access public
 */
class FormValidator
{
    public static $regexes = Array(
            'date' => "^[0-9]{1,2}[-/][0-9]{1,2}[-/][0-9]{4}\$",
            'amount' => "^[-]?[0-9]+\$",
            'number' => "^[-]?[0-9,]+\$",
            'alfanum' => "^[0-9a-zA-Z ,.-_\\s\?\!]+\$",
            'not_empty' => "[a-z0-9A-Z]+",
            'words' => "^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z \\s]*\$",
            'phone' => "^[0-9]{10,11}\$",
            'zipcode' => "^[1-9][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{2}\$",
            'plate' => "^([0-9a-zA-Z]{2}[-]){2}[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}\$",
            'price' => "^[0-9.,]*(([.,][-])|([.,][0-9]{2}))?\$",
            '2digitopt' => "^\d+(\,\d{2})?\$",
            '2digitforce' => "^\d+\,\d\d\$",
            'anything' => "^[\d\D]{1,}\$"
    );
    private $validations, $sanatations, $mandatories, $errors, $corrects, $fields;
    

    public function __construct($validations=array(), $mandatories = array(), $sanatations = array())
    {
        $this->validations = $validations;
        $this->sanitations = $sanitations;
        $this->mandatories = $mandatories;
        $this->errors = array();
        $this->corrects = array();
    }

    /**
     * Validates an array of items (if needed) and returns true or false
     *
     */
    public function validate($items)
    {
        $this->fields = $items;
        $havefailures = false;
        foreach($items as $key=>$val)
        {
            if((strlen($val) == 0 || array_search($key, $this->validations) === false) && array_search($key, $this->mandatories) === false) 
            {
                $this->corrects[] = $key;
                continue;
            }
            $result = self::validateItem($val, $this->validations[$key]);
            if($result === false) {
                $havefailures = true;
                $this->addError($key, $this->validations[$key]);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->corrects[] = $key;
            }
        }
    
        return(!$havefailures);
    }

    /**
     *
     *  Adds unvalidated class to thos elements that are not validated. Removes them from classes that are.
     */
    public function getScript() {
        if(!empty($this->errors))
        {
            $errors = array();
            foreach($this->errors as $key=>$val) { $errors[] = "'INPUT[name={$key}]'"; }

            $output = '$$('.implode(',', $errors).').addClass("unvalidated");'; 
            $output .= "new FormValidator().showMessage();";
        }
        if(!empty($this->corrects))
        {
            $corrects = array();
            foreach($this->corrects as $key) { $corrects[] = "'INPUT[name={$key}]'"; }
            $output .= '$$('.implode(',', $corrects).').removeClass("unvalidated");';   
        }
        $output = "<script type='text/javascript'>{$output} </script>";
        return($output);
    }


    /**
     *
     * Sanitizes an array of items according to the $this->sanitations
     * sanitations will be standard of type string, but can also be specified.
     * For ease of use, this syntax is accepted:
     * $sanitations = array('fieldname', 'otherfieldname'=>'float');
     */
    public function sanitize($items)
    {
        foreach($items as $key=>$val)
        {
            if(array_search($key, $this->sanitations) === false && !array_key_exists($key, $this->sanitations)) continue;
            $items[$key] = self::sanitizeItem($val, $this->validations[$key]);
        }
        return($items);
    }


    /**
     *
     * Adds an error to the errors array.
     */ 
    private function addError($field, $type='string')
    {
        $this->errors[$field] = $type;
    }

    /**
     *
     * Sanitize a single var according to $type.
     * Allows for static calling to allow simple sanitization
     */
    public static function sanitizeItem($var, $type)
    {
        $flags = NULL;
        switch($type)
        {
            case 'url':
                $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_URL;
            break;
            case 'int':
                $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT;
            break;
            case 'float':
                $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT;
                $flags = FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND;
            break;
            case 'email':
                $var = substr($var, 0, 254);
                $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL;
            break;
            case 'string':
            default:
                $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING;
                $flags = FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES;
            break;
             
        }
        $output = filter_var($var, $filter, $flags);        
        return($output);
    }
    
    /** 
     *
     * Validates a single var according to $type.
     * Allows for static calling to allow simple validation.
     *
     */
    public static function validateItem($var, $type)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($type, self::$regexes))
        {
            $returnval =  filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=> array("regexp"=>'!'.self::$regexes[$type].'!i'))) !== false;
            return($returnval);
        }
        $filter = false;
        switch($type)
        {
            case 'email':
                $var = substr($var, 0, 254);
                $filter = FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL;    
            break;
            case 'int':
                $filter = FILTER_VALIDATE_INT;
            break;
            case 'boolean':
                $filter = FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN;
            break;
            case 'ip':
                $filter = FILTER_VALIDATE_IP;
            break;
            case 'url':
                $filter = FILTER_VALIDATE_URL;
            break;
        }
        return ($filter === false) ? false : filter_var($var, $filter) !== false ? true : false;
    }       
    


}
```

Of course, keep in mind that you need to do your sql query escaping too depending on what type of db your are using (mysql_real_escape_string() is useless for an sql server for instance). You probably want to handle this automatically at your appropriate application layer like an ORM. Also, as mentioned above: for outputting to html use the other php dedicated functions like htmlspecialchars ;)

For really allowing HTML input with like stripped classes and/or tags depend on one of the dedicated xss validation packages. DO NOT WRITE YOUR OWN REGEXES TO PARSE HTML!

Comment: This looks like it might be a handy script for validating inputs, but it is *completely* irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I don’t agree with using ORM , it’s over engineering imo.

Comment: @PHP >= 8.0 gives error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)`

Comment: @Reham Fahmy: This code is from 2008. It's 2022 now.
Don't Use this. Use a framework.

Answer (score 52):

No, there is not.

First of all, SQL injection is an input filtering problem, and XSS is an output escaping one - so you wouldn't even execute these two operations at the same time in the code lifecycle.

Basic rules of thumb

- For SQL query, bind parameters
- Use [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to filter out unwanted HTML
- Escape all other output with [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and be mindful of the 2nd and 3rd parameters here.

Comment: So you only use strip_tags() or htmlspecialchars() when you know that the input has HTML that you want to get rid of or escape respectively - you are not using it for any security purpose right? Also, when you do the bind, what does it do for stuff like Bobby Tables? "Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--" Does it just escape the quotes?

Comment: If you have user data that will go into a database and later be displayed on web pages, isn't it usually read a lot more than it's written?  To me, it makes more sense to filter it once (as input) before you store it, instead of having to filter it every time you display it.  Am I missing something or did a bunch of people vote for needless performance overhead in this and the accepted answer?

Comment: Best answer for me. It's short and addresses the question well if you ask me. Is it possible to attack PHP somehow via $_POST or $_GET with some injection or is this impossible?

Comment: oh yes,  the $post and $get arrays accept all characters, but some of those characters can be used against you if the character is allowed to be enumerated in the posted php page. so if you don't escape encapsulating characters ( like ", ' and `  ) it could open up an attack vector. the ` character is often missed, and can be used to form command line execution hacks. Sanitation will prevent user input hacking, but will not help you with web application firewall hacks.

Answer (score 26):

To address the XSS issue, take a look at [HTML Purifier](http://www.htmlpurifier.org). It is fairly configurable and has a decent track record.

As for the SQL injection attacks, the solution is to use prepared statements. The [PDO library](http://www.php.net/pdo) and mysqli extension support these.

Comment: there is no "best way" to do something like sanitizing input.. Use some library, html purifier is good. These libraries have been pounded on many times. So it is much more bulletproof than anything ou can come up yourself

Comment: See also http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/ . From my understanding WordPress uses an older version, http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/2.9.2/wp-includes/kses.php

Comment: The problem with wordpress is that its not necessarily a php-sql injection attack that causes database breaches. Miss programmed plugins that store data that an xml query reveals secrets is more problematic.

Answer (score 19):

PHP 5.2 introduced the [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function.

It supports a great deal of `SANITIZE`, `VALIDATE` filters.

Answer (score 18):

There's no catchall function, because there are multiple concerns to be addressed.

1. **SQL Injection** - Today, generally, every PHP project should be using [prepared statements via PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) as a best practice, *preventing an error from a stray quote as well as a full-featured solution against injection*. It's also the most flexible & secure way to access your database.

Check out [*(The only proper) PDO tutorial*](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) for pretty much everything you need to know about PDO. (Sincere thanks to top SO contributor, @YourCommonSense, for this great resource on the subject.)

2. **XSS - Sanitize data on the way in...**

- [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) has been around a long time and is still actively updated. You can use it to sanitize malicious input, while still allowing a generous & configurable whitelist of tags. Works great with many WYSIWYG editors, but it might be heavy for some use cases.
- In other instances, where we don't want to accept HTML/Javascript at all, I've found this simple function useful (and has passed multiple audits against XSS):

  ```php
  /* Prevent XSS input */
  function sanitizeXSS () {
      $_GET   = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      $_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      $_REQUEST = (array)$_POST + (array)$_GET + (array)$_REQUEST;
  }
  ```

3. **XSS - Sanitize data on the way out...** unless you guarantee the data was properly sanitized before you add it to your database, you'll need to sanitize it before displaying it to your user, we can leverage these useful PHP functions:

- When you call `echo` or `print` to display user-supplied values, use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php) unless the data was properly sanitized safe and is allowed to display HTML.
- [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is a safe way to provide user-supplied values from PHP to Javascript

5. **Do you call external shell commands using [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) functions, or to the [`backtick`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) operator?** If so, in addition to SQL Injection & XSS you might have an additional concern to address, *users running malicious commands on your server*. You need to use [`escapeshellcmd`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) if you'd like to escape the entire command OR [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to escape individual arguments.

Comment: could mb_encode_numericentity be used instead? Since it encodes everything?

Comment: @drtechno - `mb_encode_numericentity` is discussed in the `htmlspecialchars` link on #3 XSS

Comment: From what I know, XSS is an output concern, not an input one.

Comment: @bam - you are correct, just don't miss a spot! Luckily most frameworks will handle for us when used properly.

Answer (score 18):

## Methods for safe database interaction in PHP

### Using modern versions of MySQL and PHP

#### 1. Set charset explicitly:

##### [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb");
```

##### [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

```php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8mb4', $user, $password);
```

#### 2. Use prepared statements

##### [MySQLi prepared statements:](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

```php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1'); $param = "' OR 1=1 /*";<br>$stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
$stmt->execute();
```

##### [PDO Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

Compared to MySQLi prepared statements, PDO supports more database drivers and named parameters:

```php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(["' OR 1=1 /*"]);
```

Answer (score 14):

One trick that can help in the specific circumstance where you have a page like `/mypage?id=53` and you use the id in a WHERE clause is to ensure that id definitely is an integer, like so:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  settype($id, 'integer');
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '$id'");
  # now use the result
}
```

But of course that only cuts out one specific attack, so read all the other answers. (And yes I know that the code above isn't great, but it shows the specific defence.)

Comment: I use $id = intval($id) instead :)

Comment: Casting integer is a good way to ensure only numerical data is inserted.

Comment: `$id = (int)$_GET['id']` and `$que = sprintf('SELECT ... WHERE id="%d"', $id)` is good too

Comment: perhaps `if (isset($_GET['id']) { if !( (int) $_GET['id'] === intval($_GET['id'] ) ) { throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid page id format'); } /* use a prepared statement for insert here */ };` might suit you. I prefer to make no database call at all if I can identify that a parameter is definitely not valid based on known schema it is being handed to.

Answer (score 9):

What you are describing here is two separate issues:

1. Sanitizing / filtering of user input data.
2. Escaping output.

1) User input should always be assumed to be bad.

Using prepared statements, or/and filtering with mysql_real_escape_string is definitely a must.
PHP also has filter_input built in which is a good place to start.

2) This is a large topic, and it depends on the context of the data being output. For HTML there are solutions such as htmlpurifier out there.
as a rule of thumb, always escape anything you output.

Both issues are far too big to go into in a single post, but there are lots of posts which go into more detail:

[Methods PHP output](http://shiflett.org/articles)

[Safer PHP output](https://www.lazycat.org/php-output-escaping.html)

Answer (score 8):

If you're using PostgreSQL, the input from PHP can be escaped with `pg_escape_literal()`

```php
$username = pg_escape_literal($_POST['username']);
```

From the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/es/function.pg-escape-literal.php):

> `pg_escape_literal()` escapes a literal for querying the PostgreSQL database. It returns an escaped literal in the PostgreSQL format.

Comment: **[pg_escape_literal()](https://php.net/manual/es/function.pg-escape-literal.php)** is the recommended function to use for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 6):

## You never sanitize input.

## You always sanitize output.

The transforms you apply to data to make it safe for inclusion in an SQL statement are completely different from those you apply for inclusion in HTML are completely different from those you apply for inclusion in Javascript are completely different from those you apply for inclusion in LDIF are completely different from those you apply to inclusion in CSS are completely different from those you apply to inclusion in an Email....

By all means [validate input](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2017/07/validate-input-escape-output.html) - decide whether you should accept it for further processing or tell the user it is unacceptable. But don't apply any change to representation of the data until it is about to leave PHP land.

A long time ago someone tried to invent a one-size fits all mechanism for escaping data and we ended up with "[magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)" which didn't properly escape data for all output targets and resulted in different installation requiring different code to work.

Comment: one problem with that is that its not always a database attack, and all user input should be protected from the system. not just one language type. So on your sites, when you enumerate your $_POST data, even with using binding, it could escape out enough to execute shell or even other php code.

Comment: "its not always a database attack" : "The transforms you apply to data to make it safe for inclusion in an SQL statement are completely different from those...."

Comment: "all user input should be protected from the system" : no the system should be protected from user input.

Comment: well I ran out of words, but yes the input needs to be prevented from effecting the system operation. to clarify this...

Comment: Both input and output should be sanitized.

Comment: I understood. The form of input is determined of the purpose and we can't sanitize input to fit everywhere. But I don't agree with this practice because even with inserted input (i.e. in database) it can be vulnerable for processing it. We should ensure to prevent any vulnerability at every stage of our data processing. Popular custom is that data we store in database is safe and a lot of developers don't care about sanitization of 'input' in storage.

Comment: You did not understand. You are describing OUTPUT from PHP not INPUT.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to avoid mistakes in sanitizing input and escaping data is using PHP framework like [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), [Nette](http://nette.org/en/) etc. or part of that framework (templating engine, database layer, ORM).

Templating engine like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or Latte has output escaping on by default - you don't have to solve manually if you have properly escaped your output depending on context (HTML or Javascript part of web page).

Framework is automatically sanitizing input and you should't use $_POST, $_GET or $_SESSION variables directly, but through mechanism like routing, session handling etc.

And for database (model) layer there are ORM frameworks like Doctrine or wrappers around PDO like Nette Database.

You can read more about it here - [What is a software framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964140/what-is-a-framework-what-does-it-do-why-do-we-need-a-framework)

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add that on the subject of output escaping, if you use php DOMDocument to make your html output it will automatically escape in the right context. An attribute (value="") and the inner text of a <span> are not equal.
To be safe against XSS read this:
[OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Speaking of OWASP cheat sheets, my personal opinion is that the best way to educate PHP developers in secure coding is to hire the services of an ethical hacker or to learn how to use and run Kali Linux / Metasploit, adn then demo various exploits. When developers see how an exploit actually works, the impact is much higher than a dozen SO Q&A's. Then interested developers begin to study file formats, protocols, query logging, demand Wireshark, etc. Till then, they follow Q&a's on hope and faith. Again, this is a personal opinion. YMMV.